# Filtering array elements based on 'in' condition in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an arrayList which contains employees information like employeename, grade, designation. I have a multiselect component in my view which returns an array of grades like `[1,2,3]` once we choose `grade1`, `grade2`, `grade3` from the multiselect dropdown. Is there a way to filter my employeelist based on these grades array? Similar like this:

```
this.employeeList.filter(x=> x.grade in (grade1,grade2,grade3));
```

Or is there otherway to acheive this? Basically I need to filter my employeelist based on multiselect values. Please suggest as I am new to typescript. 
 Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you deal with regular variables, you can just wrap them into additional array `[var1, var2, ...]` and use `includes()` for check:

```js
const grade1 = 1,
      grade2 = 2,
      grade3 = 3;
const employeeList = [
  { grade: 1 },
  { grade: 3 },
  { grade: 4 },
  { grade: 8 },
  { grade: 9 }
];

const result = employeeList.filter(x => [grade1,grade2,grade3].includes(x.grade));
console.log(result) // should print the array with objects {"grade": 1} and {"grade": 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use something like:

```
x => [grade1,grade2,grade3].indexOf(x) != -1
```